# Python - Import _brcypt - PyUnicodeUCS4_FromUnicode

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko, bcrypt

I need to install/use paramiko in a server with python 2.7

I install paramiko with pip without any problem but, when i try to import it, it´s fails

The error is:

ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromUnicode

It´s an old machine without any documentation, it´s a mess.... i use paramiko in other servers without any problem

> > > import paramiko
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/**init**.py", line 22, in 
> > >           from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
> > >         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 90, in 
> > >           from paramiko.ed25519key import Ed25519Key
> > >         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/ed25519key.py", line 17, in 
> > >           import bcrypt
> > >         File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/bcrypt/**init**.py", line 25, in 
> > >           from . import _bcrypt
> > >       ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromUnicode

error message:

ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromUnicode